# Airflow try number issue

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I have encountered an error during testing , does anyone have any lead on this.

#### Code:

```
relative_path = self._render_filename(ti, ti.try_number)
```

#### Error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'try_number
```

Comment: can you share pleas the full test?

Comment: I am using base hook to connect to http connection and below is the error             
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py", line 285, in _init_file
    relative_path = self._render_filename(ti, ti.try_number)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'try_number'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error in Airflow usually happens because the BaseHook class can no longer receive an `str` parameter[1], only a `ti` (TaskInstance) [2]. You can simply create the BaseHook without providing any parameters like:

```py
my_hook = BaseHook()
```

[1] https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/hooks/base.html#BaseHook

[2] https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.6/_modules/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.html

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, but in my case I was initialising the BaseHook with string

```
super().__init__("mystring")
```

removing this "mystring" and initialising the base hook with None works for me.